How to merge UV maps of a single mesh?
I have a single mesh with multiple UV maps that I need to combine. Can I do this without separating the mesh? I'm trying to find a good way out of having to manually sort through 100 vertex groups. I believe that I will need the mesh intact to apply animation to it as well.
EDIT: I'll demonstrate with these pictures. When I select all the mesh then I can display various UV maps that I have made. Alternatively, I could select vertex groups instead of everything at once.



Hello, what do you mean by merging UV maps? Also, what does it have to do with sorting vertex groups? Could you please tell a bit more?

I updated my original post. Please take a look at it.

Separate model by UVs into individual objects ... Name all uvmaps same and than Join Ctrl+J into single object ... Like that all UVs are merged into a one UVmap. Like this tutorial ... probably duplicate of this BSE

When you say "Separate model by UVs into individual objects" I don't know how to do this. Also, in the video when he says, "Turn on UV sync"... I don't know what UV sync is or how to enable it. And about the thread, When I try to name my UV maps the same thing they just automatically rename to stay different. Like when I try to name two objects "UV0" the second one will rename to "UV0.001"

How to separate is explained by video ... "UV sync" is shown at 0:30 of video ... renaming UVs has to happen after separation into individual objects (also shown in video at 1:00 ... just check it more carefully :)

Well I found the UV sync feature but unfortunately when I try to separate by selection the program just locks up. I let it sit for 30 minutes and it never recovered.

Sorry, I don't know how to help with that. Testing with default cubes work. You can try to share simplified blend file (via blend-exchange.com copy-paste given code into your original post via edit)) ... with just a part of your character containing at least two UVs, so we can try.

Well I figured something out although I gave up on merging the UV map. Instead of starting from the PSK/PSA format, I started from FBX which was much better about the texturing.

Great you found solution. Since you are not expecting answer consider delete your Q. Like now system here will be poking up. Thank you keep this site organised.
